# Installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, partition, system-installation

I am about to install Ubuntu Server in my PC at work, which has already Windows 7 installed.

I was about to create the partition and then I saw they look right now like this:
[image: Photo]

You can see the reserved partition was created in another Disk as the one where Windows is installed. I suppose this was a mistake when installing windows.

Now my question is: Could I install Ubuntu in the free partition or should I first move the reserved partition and then install Ubuntu?

Comment: What reserved partition? Your image is very hard to read and, even when opening the original, is in German. That looks like some Windows tool which shows, I guess, physical hard drives. Right? When asking questions, please make sure everyone can understand. As it stands, only someone who is both familiar with Windows tools (most of us here are not) and has a basic understanding of German would be able to understand. I can *guess*, but that's not good enough since I might guess wrong. And what mistake? How many drives do you actually have? What makes you think there's a problem here?

Comment: Please include the output of `parted -l`, which can be run from a *Ubuntu* CD.

Comment: I am sorry, will asap post an Gparted screenshot in english. i have just no access to linux right now...

Comment: Linux is quite malleable about how it's installed. As agc said, yes you can use the free space on whichever drive you want, and even create Linux partitions across multiple drives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could install *Ubuntu* on the *232GB* of free space on the first hard drive (*233GB*), that space can be subdivided into different partitions as needed.

If speed matters, using partitions on both hard drives can improve hard disk seek time:

1. *Ubuntu* would run a little faster if some space is made on the *2nd* hard drive (*466GB*) for the *swap* partition, or perhaps a */tmp* partition.
2. It may help to compare the speed of the drives, (*i.e.* with `hdparm -t /dev/sda`, and `hdparm -t /dev/sdb`), and if there's a significant difference put the data partitions, (*i.e.* `/home`), on the slower drive.